# Spring jdbc exception: B cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB

Tags: spring, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a byte[] into an oracle.sql.BLOB column using spring jdbc 3.0. And I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8752)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8286)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8868)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)|
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:166)|
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:166)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:356)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgTypePreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgTypePreparedStatementSetter.java:97)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgTypePreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgTypePreparedStatementSetter.java:79)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:815)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:811)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)|at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:867)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:871)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.executeInsertInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:366)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.doExecute(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:356)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert.execute(SimpleJdbcInsert.java:118)|
....
```

The byte[] is being constructed from a ByteBuffer object.

```
byte[] byte_array = byte_buffer.array();
```

I tried inserting a java.sql.Blob type as well, but that gave a similar exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8752)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8286)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8868)|
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)|
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:166)|
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:166)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:356)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)|
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
....
```

The java.sql.Blob is also being created from a ByteBuffer object.

```
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(byte_buffer.array());
```

It looks like [StatementCreatorUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/StatementCreatorUtils.java#L289) does not handle java.sql.Blob the way it handles CLOB or NCLOB. Is there a work-around for this? Or is there a different java sql type that I should be using?

Comment: How are you creating the `java.sql.Blob` value?  Please edit your question to include the code that creates the `java.sql.Blob` value.

Answer (score 0):

Let the type to be `BINARY` instead of `BLOB` (`Types.BINARY`)

I used this way and it's executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Spring's `SqlLobValue`. Attach your `byte[]` value to the query parameter map like this:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("blobParam", new SqlLobValue(byteArrayValue, lobHandler), Types.BLOB);
```

Where `lobHandler` is a `LobHandler` bean (i.e `org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler`).